# Why is $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^r-1}-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

Why is $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^r-1}-1$? This is mentioned on my lecture notes but I don’t have a reference for this fact (and I couldn’t find it online).

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_{p^r}^\times$ has $p^r-1$ elements so all its elements are roots of $X^{p^r-1}-1$. This is a polynomial of degree $p^r-1$ so it has at most $p^r-1$ roots. Therefore $\Bbb{F}_{p^r}^\times$ is the set of roots of $X^{p^r-1}-1$.